# I'm looking to list [product_categories] and exclude just one category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to display all my Woocommerce categories on a page except one. Are there any Woocommerce shortcodes that can handle this or do I need to write up a function?

```
[product_categories ids="-170"]
```

Alternatively this is the only category that has child categories, so if there's a way to show all categories except those with a child category that would work too.

This is what I've tried but I'm a newbie and I'm sure I'm missing something.

```
if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-823") ) {
    $args = array(
'hide_empty'               => 1,
'exclude'                  =>array(170) // desire id
    );

    $categories = get_categories($args);

}
```

Comment: For your PHP array, I hope this helps you: https://wpza.net/woocommerce/how-to-loop-through-woocommerce-categories/

Comment: well i see that part of my issue is that I'm trying to run php code in my js file. ughhh i'm so frustrated i feel like this shouldn't be this hard :(

Comment: You could do this in the PHP file using `<?php if ( is_page( 823 ) ) {//code here} ?>`